# The error says that user_input is undefined, what to do?

Tags: python

The code is below. Please help.

```
num1 = float(raw_input("Enter a number"))
num2 = float(raw_input("Enter another number"))
while True:
    print("Select one of the following options")
    print("'Add' for addition")
    print("'Subtract' for subtraction")
    print("'Multiply' for multipication")
    print("'Divide' for division")
    print("'Quit' for closing the application")
    user_input == raw_input("Enter your choice: ")

if user_input == 'Add':
    print num1 + num2
elif user_input == 'Subtract':
    if num1 < num2:
        print num2 - num1
    else:
        print num1 - num2
elif user_input == 'Multiply':
    print num1 * num2
elif user_input == 'Divide':
    print num1/num2
elif user_input == 'Quit':
    break
```

[The image shows the code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VChyK.png)

Comment: You have a problem with = vs ==

Answer (score 1):

you are using incorrect equality assignment. == instead of =

```
user_input == raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
```

should be

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
```

Comment: where? as it is this answer is incomplete

Comment: user_input == raw_input("Enter your choice: ")

should be user_input = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")

Answer (score 1):

```
user_input == raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
```

should be

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
```

with only one equal character

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
user_input == raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
```

to

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
```